# XPath test if any ancestor has a specific child element

Tags: xml, xslt, path, ancestor

I am still struggling with my XML Schema and I just do not seem to be able to get it right. I need to write an XSLT assertion to ensure that every nested `<instruction>` element has either a child element `<stroke>` or any ancestor has a `<stroke>` element (XOR).

This is an example of a valid XML:

```
<program>
    <instruction>
        <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
        <stroke>
            <standardStroke>backstroke</standardStroke>
        </stroke>
    </instruction>
   <instruction>
        <repetition>
            <repetitionCount>3</repetitionCount>
            <stroke>
                <standardStroke>freestyle</standardStroke>
            </stroke>
            <instruction>
                <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
            </instruction>
            <instruction>
                <lengthAsDistance>200</lengthAsDistance>
            </instruction>
            <instruction>
                <repetition>
                    <repetitionCount>4</repetitionCount>
                    <instruction>
                        <lengthAsDistance>100</lengthAsDistance>
                    </instruction>
                </repetition>
            </instruction>
        </repetition>
    </instruction>
</program>
```

I then tried:

`<xs:assert test="(stroke and not(ancestor::stroke) or not(stroke) and ancestor::stroke) or (.. is root() and repetition)"/>`

The test for the child element `<stroke>` works fine, but the test for any ancestors having a `<stroke>` child does not work as expected. The  test for all `<instruction>` directly under the root `<program>` also does not seem to work.

Thank you up front for any help that you can offer.

Comment: `not(ancestor::stroke)` test whether the element has an ancestor which _is_ a `stroke`, not an ancestor which _has_ a `stroke` child, if that's what you're trying to test for.

Comment: I do indeed need to check if any ancestor has a child stroke element. How can I test that? Thank you!

Comment: You can test that by `not(ancestor::*/stroke)`.

Comment: Do you want to also check that you don't have more than one stroke as a child of an ancestor? I imagine that you probably want to ensure that an `instruction` has exactly one stroke, either as a child, or as a child of an ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Schematron, where XPath can be used for assertions, you would want something like

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="instruction[not(descendant::instruction | ancestor::instruction)]">
            <assert test="stroke">There is no associated stroke element.</assert>
        </rule>
        <rule context="instruction//instruction">
            <assert test="stroke or ancestor::repetition/stroke">There is no associated stroke element.</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

For XSD 1.1 assertions, I am not sure how freely you can navigate around ancestors, with Saxon EE the following works for me:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="program">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="instruction"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert id="stroke"
        test="every $instruction in instruction
        satisfies (
        (
        not($instruction//instruction) and $instruction/stroke
        )
        or
        (every $nested-instruction in $instruction//instruction
        satisfies $nested-instruction/ancestor::repetition/stroke)
        )"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me as possible that you might actually want to ensure that an `instruction` has *exactly one* `stroke` element among its children and the children of any of its ancestors. If that is the assertion you want, then the following XPath should do it:

```xml
count(ancestor-or-self::*/stroke)=1
```